# When use AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-4

I am working with Spring 4.0.7

I did a research about configure Spring MVC through JavaConfig.

Practically until yesterday I have seen two configurations using these two options

1. *extends* `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`
2. *extends* `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` **and** *implements* `WebApplicationInitializer`

**Note**: (2) are two classes, one for extension and the other for implementation

I am using (2) because I have found many examples where I am able to configure converters, formatters, resources handlers etc…

But in the latest days I have tried to help a question on StackOverflow and I did realize (1) exists.. I did some overview on Google about (1) and exists some examples working with (1)

My question is how the title of this post describe.

Thank You

Comment: Split your deployment configuration from your context configuration.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

With the release of the Servlet 3.0 spec it became possible to configure your Servlet Container with (almost) no xml. For this there is the [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html)  in the Servlet specification. In this class you can register filters, listeners, servlets etc. as you would traditionally do in a `web.xml`.

Spring provides a an implementation the [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) which knows how to handle [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) classes. Spring also provides a couple of base classes to extend to make your life easier and the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is one of those. It registers
a `ContextLoaderlistener` (optionally) and a `DispatcherServlet` and allows you to easily add configuration classes to load for both classes and to apply filters to the `DispatcherServlet` and to provide the servlet mapping.

The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is for configuring Spring MVC, the replacement of the xml file loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` for configuring Spring MVC. The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` should be used for a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration 
    extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer
{ ... }
```

I wouldn't recommend mixing those as they are basically 2 different concerns. The first is for configuring the servlet container, the latter for configuring Spring MVC.

You would want to split those into 2 classes.

For the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

For bootstrapping the application.

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {RootConfig.class};
    }
    
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()  {
        return new Class[] {WebConfiguration .class};
    }
    
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

An added advantage is that you now can use the convenience classes provided by Spring instead of manually configuring the `DispatcherServlet` and/or `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: Yes, is not wise mix (1) and (2), currently I am working with (2), therefore (`extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and implements WebApplicationInitializer`)

Comment: That is actually mixing the 2 strategies. You now have a single class that is responsible for configuring the servlet container and for configuring the Spring application. I would have 2 classes one for configuring the application and one for the servlet container.

Comment: I am confused, I have seen some examples about using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and WebApplicationInitializer, I only use these two *objects*, one to replace the web.xml and the other to configure Spring MVC.

Comment: The Spring Core training material is working with the two elements mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: What classes do you use? Thank You.

Comment: No you have a single object with 2 responsibilities. Of course you can do it, but for a larger applicatation I wouldn't recommend it. Just create a class that configures the context, generally extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and pass it the class that should be annotated with `@Configurable` and extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. That way you have 2 classes both having a single responsibility.

Comment: Oh, you understood in a wrong way, I have a class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to configure Spring MVC, and I have **other** class that implements WebApplicationInitializer to configure the two context, the server and web side.

Comment: I had a strange issue with Abstract...ServletInitializer. If anyone can help please post there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498024/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-repository-found-for

Comment: Where can I get the `RootConfig.class`?

Answer (score 23):

To start from the beginning it is worth looking into how servlet container starts.

- [SpringServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) is bootstrapped automatically by any Servlet 3.0 container.
- SpringServletContainerInitializer  looks for classes implementing WebApplicationInitializer (link to [spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html); also well described in "[Spring In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition)" 4th edition by Craig Walls, p.135).

So to start - SpringServletContainerInitializer has to find the right class implementing **WebApplicationInitializer**. There are two ways of making it happen:

1. One is by implementing [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) on its own; the interface was introduced in Spring 3.1
2. The second is by extending [AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) class which also implements WebApplicationInitializer. The class was introduced in Spring 3.2 for convenience and it is "the preferred approach for applications that use Java-based Spring configuration." - see the link. It enables you to start servlet application context as well as root application context.

I would also like to higlight that [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) you mention should not be confused with WebApplicationInitializer. As it name suggests - it has to do with configuring "Mvc". It is an adapter class that implements empty methods from [WebMvcConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html). You use it when you configure your Mvc controller with [@EnableWebMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) annotation.

Hope this helps.