# Transaction management for starter bean in Spring 4 + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

In my `Spring MVC` + `Hibernate` app I have XML-configured started bean:

```
<bean name="starter" init-method="create" class="foo.CreateDefaultUserBean" lazy-init="false"/>
```

I've also configured transaction management:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And `CreateDefaultUserBean` has autowired `SessionFactory`:

```
public class CreateDefaultUserBean {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void create() {
        User adminUser = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("login", username)).uniqueResult();
         // ...
    }
}
```

So it fails with `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread` exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'starter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a transactional proxy is already created when the init method is called. Hence doing transactional work in a init method will generally not work as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method. You will have to use a `TransactionTemplate` or use the `PlatformTransactionManager` yourself to manage the tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the current session is created and bound to current thread using a dedicated aspect applied on @Transactionnal annotated methods.
- Spring aspects use JDK / cglib **dynamic** proxies
- Dynamic proxies have the same contract that the proxied object and encapsulate it. when Spring injects you a bean, it injects the proxy in place of the raw object

So Spring builds your bean (using the default constructor and an eventual init method) then encapsulates it in a proxy and inject the proxy in place of the bean. the init method is so invocated directly and transactionnal aspects is not applied ; there isn't so any current session nor transaction available at this point.

Same problem and workaround than here [@Transactional on @PostConstruct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So, is my workaround posted here correct?

Comment: well your workaround creates a session and bind it to the current thread but transactionnal aspect is still not applied (the transactionnal annotation is ignored).

Comment: @Gab so what would be the fix for the issue ?

Comment: direct injection of txManager and manual (or using spring TransactionTemplate) transaction handling.

Comment: @Gab and what about `session.beginTransaction()` and manually `commit` or `rollback` it?

Comment: you can indeed but only here, mixing container and user managed transaction is not a good idea otherwise

Answer (score 1):

As workaround I've found that I can just `openSession()` instead of using `currentSession()`:

`Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();`

In this case `@Transactional` annotation is also useless. This doesn't explain why does `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread` exception occur in described configuration, but helps obtain desired result.

Comment: But isn’t the whole point of using spring transaction management is to avoid creating and destroying sessions ?

Comment: @praveen I agree, so it was my question. Gab said that it can be used in this case.

Comment: @Andremonly can you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562787/hibernateexception-couldnt-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current there is no TransactionInterceptor in your stack trace too..