# Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

Whhen trying to test caching capabilities of Hibernate's (version 4) EHCache between transactions - it fails: `Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context`.

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class, CachingConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PersistenceContext
@Transactional
public class EHCacheTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Test
    public void testTransactionCaching(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(session.get(CustomerEntity.class, 1));
        Query query = session.createQuery("from CustomerEntity where CustomerEntity.customerId<10").setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("customer");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities = query.list();
        System.out.println(customerEntities);

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();

        TestTransaction.start();

        Session sessionNew =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(sessionNew.get(CustomerEntity.class, 1));
        Query anotherQuery = sessionNew.createQuery("from CustomerEntity where CustomerEntity.customerId<10");
        anotherQuery.setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("customer");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<CustomerEntity> customerListfromCache = anotherQuery.list();
        System.out.println(customerListfromCache);

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
    }
}
```

The manual programmatic Transaction handling was implemented the way Spring 4.x suggests in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-programmatic-tx-mgt).

**ApplicationConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence" }, transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-postgresql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence" })
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model" });

        final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource applicationDataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() { // TODO: Really need this?
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() { // TODO: Really need this?
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(); // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562787/hibernateexception-couldnt-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");

        // Envers properties
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", env.getProperty("envers.audit_table_suffix")); // TODO: Really need this?

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**CachingConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig implements CachingConfigurer {
    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("myCacheName");
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxElementsInMemory(1000);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context [DefaultTestContext@d8355a8 testClass = EHCacheTest, testInstance = com.hibernate.query.performance.EHCacheTest@3532ec19, testMethod = testTransactionCaching@EHCacheTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@59fa1d9b testClass = EHCacheTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.hibernate.query.performance.config.ApplicationConfig, class com.hibernate.query.performance.config.CachingConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

How to make it work?

---

**Update:**

Made it work by adding, not sure though if `@TestExecutionListeners` is really required:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@TestExecutionListeners({})
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@Transactional requires a bean with name transactionManager in your application context if not specified explictly. Specify the transaction manager you want to use with your test using the @Transaction annotation value attribute

For example if you want to use hibernateTransactionManager specify this as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class, CachingConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PersistenceContext
@Transactional("hibernateTransactionManager")
public class EHCacheTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
}
```

Otherwise rename the transaction manager you want to use to have the default name transactionManager

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() { // TODO: Really need this?
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already [answered by ekem chitsiga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348154/466862), the proper solution is to define a transaction manager. However, you can workaround this issue by using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. This will result in the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` not to require a transaction manager, but the effect of this is that your test is not actually transactional, so you should then ask why it is even annotated as such.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, I revolved it by:

adding on my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement // +++ added annotation
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.stackoverflow.my.project")
@PropertySource("application-tests.properties")
@ComponentScan({ "com.stackoverflow.my.project" })
public class H2JpaConfig {

@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

and adding on my test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { H2JpaConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional("transactionManager") // +++ add transaction manager
public class MyDaoClassTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests { // +++ extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests 
    @Autowired
    private MyDaoClass myDaoClass;
}
```

it works fine for me.
Thanks for reading