# Can't use @Transactional in Spring Boot Test

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I've created a simple application using Spring Boot, Kotlin & Mongodb. Now I would like to use the @Transactional annotation in the test CustomerServiceIntegrationTest to make sure each test case rolls back any changes it did to the database.

When I add @Transactional I get the message `Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test`.

Writing to the db otherwise works fine.

What did I miss?

https://github.com/urswiss/customer

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386449/spring-data-and-mongodb-simple-roll-back-with-spring-within-transactional and https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data it all depends on the versions you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344471/failed-to-retrieve-platformtransactionmanager-for-transactional-test-for-test-c)

Comment: So it’s because Mongo has no transactions. Thanks!