# Why EhCache not caching this query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache, embedded-tomcat-7

Looking at Hibernate metrics, it appears that there is no use of second level cache for specific query:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1242, for class: com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Store
INFO: Session Metrics {
    28572828 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    6518980126 nanoseconds spent preparing 1396 JDBC statements;
    9007649169 nanoseconds spent executing 1396 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    77148015 nanoseconds spent performing 1486 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    71112 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1242, for class: com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Store
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    25857570 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    3010741744 nanoseconds spent preparing 1396 JDBC statements;
    8950885558 nanoseconds spent executing 1396 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    54506271 nanoseconds spent performing 1486 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    20938 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Code:

```
@Override
    public List<Customer> getFilteredCustomers(String filter) {
        Session session = null;
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                Query query = session.createQuery("select c " +
                        " from Rental r, Customer c join fetch c.address address " +
                        " where r.customer = c " +
                        " and r.returnDate is null");
                query.setCacheable(true);
                customers = (List<Customer>)query.list();
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }finally {
                if (session!=null) session.close();
            }

        return customers;
    }
```

**Configuration:**

```
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("theEHCache");
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxElementsInMemory(1000);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfig:**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence" }, transactionManagerRef = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-postgresql.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.hibernate.query.performance" })
@EnableCaching
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model" });

        final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return emf;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource applicationDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction.
     * The DataSource that Hibernate uses needs to be JTA-enabled in such a scenario (see container setup).
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562787/hibernateexception-couldnt-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "managed"); // https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region_prefix", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region_prefix"));
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
    @Bean
    public EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }
}
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns=""
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true"
         maxBytesLocalHeap="150M">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />


    <cache name="customerCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="10000"
           maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>

    <defaultCache
           maxElementsInMemory="10000"
           maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

**persistence-postgresql.properties**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region_prefix=""
```

Console:

```
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
54  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
54  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
55  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
55  org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache <init>
INFO: HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: "".org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
55  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
55  org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache <init>
INFO: HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: "".org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
55  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
55  org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
57  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".customerCache]; using defaults.
58  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
58  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
58  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
58  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
58  org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache <init>
INFO: HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: "".org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
58  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
58  org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache <init>
INFO: HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: "".org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
58  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
59  org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named ["".customerCache]; using defaults.
:03  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher'
:03  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on a few unit tests I came to conclusion derived from results of test:

The **given query** is not cached in both cases: where there is present `join fetch c.address address` or not. However, `join fetch c.address address` speeds up the query more than 2x times. If anyone can explain why underlying frameworks think the query is not worth caching I would be glad.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but don't you have to set a provider for second-level cache? Like `hibernate.cache.provider_class` with `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider` value?  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm

Comment: Just another thought - have you also tried with `query.setCacheRegion` ?

Comment: no difference as I set `query.setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Customer");`. I noticed if I comment out first part of query it gets significantly faster `/*"select c " +*/`. 6 seconds vs 2 seconds.